# Does $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{e^{x^2/2}-\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration

Does the improper integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{e^{x^{2}/2}-\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ converge?

I've tried using different tests with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only problem is at $0$ so using the Taylor series we have
$$\frac{x^3}{e^{x^2/2}-\cos x}\sim_0\frac{x^3}{1+\frac{x^2}{2}-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}=x$$
so the integral is convergent since the integrand has a finite limit at $0$.

Comment: I didn't need for this simple calculus a computer program, did you need?

Comment: You can also use de l'hospital rule twice with $x \to 0^+$ and see that the $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x^3}{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} - \cos x} = 0$.